# How to get type by using object property in generic typescript

Tags: typescript

How can I get type by object property from generic?
What I want to do is ▼

```
type A = {data:string, name: string};

interface B<T> {
  data: T['data'] // error.. want to be expected as string
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript does not know that `T` should have a property `data`. A constraint would fix this.

```
type A = { data:string, name: string };

interface B<T extends { data: any }>{
  data: T['data'] 
}
```